# How is my check for undefined still getting through?

Tags: javascript

I have the following JS code where I check `undefined`, but when it hits the check for length it crashes because it is is `undefined`?

```
if(quantity === undefined){
    if(quantity.length > 0){  <--- still error as it is undefined?
      comments = comments + "<br>Qty: " + quantity;
    }
  } else {
    comments = comments + "<br>Qtyy: not sure" ;
  }
```

Comment: how can `quantity` have length is it is `undefined`

Comment: Post a [mcve] .

Comment: Read your code.  You're check to make sure it _is_ undefined.  It is.

Comment: Did you mean `!== undefined`?

Comment: You want to check if it's *not* defined. Read your condition again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## You have only one main issue

Your comparison is wrong because you're trying to use the variable `quantity` when this is `undefined`

```
if(quantity === undefined)
                ^
```

## Look at this code snippet with that fix

```js
let quantity;
let comments = '';

let comment = () => {
  if (quantity) {
    if (quantity.length > 0) {
      comments = comments + "<br>Qty: " + quantity;
    }
  } else {
    comments = comments + "<br>Qtyy: not sure";
  }
}

comment();
console.log(comments);

quantity = '5';
comments = '';

comment();
console.log(comments);
```

See? now is working your code.

Comment: Sorry late night. Stupid mistake.

Comment: @jdog it happens :-)

Answer (score 1):

In JavaScript `undefined` is a type. Use `typeof` and `!==` instead of `===` like the following:

```js
var comments = '';
if(typeof(quantity) !== 'undefined'){
  if(quantity.length > 0){
    comments = comments + "<br>Qty: " + quantity;
  }else {
    comments = comments + "<br>Qtyy: not sure" ;
  }
}
else{
  console.log('undefined')
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When a variable is declared in JavaScript without initialization, it is assigned to a special value called `undefined`.

`undefined` means the type of the variable is not defined still as JavaScript is a runtime language it allows programmers to define variable type in runtime. And `undefined` has no property associated with it.

In your code, the `quantity` is checked against `undefined`. If it is `undefined` it enters the second condition of `quantity.length > 0` which is wrong. Hence, the first condition should be `(quantity !== undefined)`.

Answer (score -1):

```js
let quantity = undefined;

if (quantity === undefined) { // quantity is undefined so enter the if...
  if (quantity.length > 0) { //at this point quantity is undefined so .length fails and causes an error
      comments = comments + "<br>Qty: " + quantity;
  }
} else {
  comments = comments + "<br>Qtyy: not sure";
}
```